# azure active directory authentication for remote users

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Currently our company has an intranet web app (built with asp.net) using windows authentication verifying users against an in house active directory to be able to access the app. We are thinking about moving the app out to azure and extending our active directory in house out to azure as well.

We are stumbling upon how this works when a user is trying to access the web app once it is setup in azure if users are working remotely and not in the office. Currently the user will log in through a juniper SSL client when remote to get into the local domain. Once they do so they can access the intranet web app since they are now on the domain and can be verified by AD.

How would this work if we put our web app out into azure? Do they offer a front end a user can log into (similar to juniper) which will then verify them against the azure ad, and only then they can access the web app based on windows authentication?

NOTE: Our goal if possible is for a DR solution and if the office is not accessible we would like to bypass needing to use juniper to get onto the domain first before going up to azure and into the web app.

Answer (score 2):

Yon want to use your local Windows Active Directory as an identity provider to Windows Azure, I think you're looking for a SSO solution, it can be archived with the Access Control Service or Windows Azure Active Directory.

About these two service, please read: [Azure Active Directory is the future of ACS](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2013/06/22/azure-active-directory-is-the-future-of-acs.aspx).

This [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/plankytronixx/archive/2011/06/14/click-by-click-video-using-on-premise-active-directory-to-authenticate-to-a-windows-azure-app.aspx) provides a video on how to do it with ACS.

This post: [Windows Azure ACS with Active Directory as identity provider for SSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929921/windows-azure-acs-with-active-directory-as-identity-provider-for-sso), also should be helpful.

Comment: Thanks I will check out your links!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to achieve authentication against Active Directory for a browser-based application is to use Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS). The application delegates authentication to the website exposed by ADFS using the WS-Federation passive authentication protocol.

1. When an unauthenticated user hits your site they are redirected to ADFS.
2. If the user is on the domain, ADFS will silently sign them in, otherwise it asks the user for their domain credentials (Windows login and username).
3. ADFS redirects the user back to the site with an authentication token that identifies the user.
4. The site validates the token and sets up the user's identity.

This completely replaces Windows Integrated Authentication (which is what I presume you're using) and switches your application to a claims-based system that no longer has intimate knowledge of Active Directory or the domain.

This solution requires that your ADFS website can be exposed publicly, so users outside of your network can reach it. There are plenty of articles for configuring various different levels of secure ADFS, but this is more of a networking and infrastructure problem than  a programming one.

If that's not palatable, you can provision a Windows Azure Active Directory instance to provide the same functionality as ADFS. You would have to set up sync between your on-premise Active Directory forest and the Azure instance, which would require exposing part of your Active Directory infrastructure to Windows Azure.

In either case, you must make the switch to using WS-Federation and claims-based identity to remove your dependency on Windows Integrated Authentication.

Answer (score 2):

What you really want to do is start up Visual Studio 2013 and try the Multi Organizational Web Application Template and see if thats not what you are seeking. Then migrate your current app to that.

It gives you a place where 3party companies can sign up for your application (administrators of their WAAD can do this) and it will be added to their WAAD.

Then users of their organization can log into your app when the organization is signed up.

If you are working with Owin, i just made a owin sample that shows this using the alpha owin package (this is not production ready yet). But the VS template for multi organizational sign in is a great place to start and it does exactly what you are asking.

http://www.s-innovations.net/Blog/2014/02/22/Multi-Organizational-sign-in-with-WsFederation-owin-middleware